# I'm having an issue with the drawing action

Tags: processing

I'm new to processing so I'm confused as to where to read or start.  Right now i have to make the code work to have the ellipse draw colors when i press on the boxes. Though it does it when i just hover my mouse over the box and continues going without my mouse on it. How can i have it work to keep it only drawing when i click on it and either click on it again or release my press action. Any help would be appreciative. I just took out the part where I drew the rectangles and ellipse

```
float x=0;
float r=255;
float b =255;
float g= 255;
float i=20;
float t=60;
float a=0;
float c=0;
float e=0;
float f=0;

...

 if (mousePressed==true) {
if (mouseX> 19 && mouseX<40 && mouseY>19 && mouseY<41 ) {//move up give     range
t=t+1;
}

if (mouseX>60 && mouseX<80 && mouseY>19 && mouseY<41) {//move down
t=t-1;
}

if (mousePressed==true) {

if (mouseX> 19 && mouseX<40 && mouseY>19 && mouseY<41 )
 {//move up give range
t=t+1;
}
if (mouseX>60 && mouseX<80 && mouseY>19 && mouseY<41) {//move down 
t=t-1;
    }
    } else if (mouseX>100 && mouseX<120 && mouseY>19 && mouseY<41) {// draw line(series of elipses)
e=10;
f=10;
r=255;
b=255;
g=255;
a=i+10;
c=t+20;
fill(r, g, b);


} else if (mouseX>140 && mouseX<160 && mouseY>19 && mouseY<41) {// green line
//e=10;
f=10;
r=0;
g=255;
b=0;
fill (r, g, b);


} else if (mouseX>180 && mouseX<200 && mouseY>19 && mouseY<41) {// blue line

r=0;
g=0;
b=255;
fill(r, g, b);

}  else if (mouseX>220 && mouseX<240 && mouseY>19 && mouseY<41) {// red line
e=10;
f=10;
r=255;
g=0;
b=0;
fill(r, g, b);

}

} else if (mouseX>260 && mouseX<238 && mouseY>19 && mouseY<41) {// pink         line 

r=255;
g=0;
b=255;
fill(r, g, b);
}
}
}
```

Comment: We seem to lack a lot of context. What language, what environment is this for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is correct for detecting if the mouse is pressed, and where the pointer is located: `if (mousePressed==true)` and
`if (mouseX> 19 && mouseX<40 && mouseY>19 && mouseY<41 )`.

Now you can declare a variable for each box that the user can press, indicating whether that particular box is being pressed by the mouse at the current moment: `boolean isPressed_Box1 = false;` and `boolean isPressed_Box2 = false;`.  Then inside the `draw()` function, check each box rectangle, to whether the mouse is within that box, and pressed.  Set the corresponding variable to `true`, otherwise set it to `false`.  At this point, now each variable should have the correct value.  So all your handling for the mouse is finished.  Add another series of `if()` statements, one for each box, to draw an appropriate color rectangle depending on each corresponding variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. For the boolean is Pressed function would that be under the rectangles in draw() or before the void setup() where float is?

Comment: If you put them before `setup()` then they are global variables, which is appropriate if you need to remember the value from one `draw()` call to the next.  When drawing, do you need to know whether the mouse was pressed at some point in the past?  If not, and you only need to know about the mouse press for the current drawing, then put them inside of `draw()` at the top of the function so they'll be local variables within that function, and their value is not kept when the function finishes.

Comment: Yes, the mouse works fine when I pressed the box that creates the action to the ellipse to color as it moves right, but then it doesn't stop afterwards. It also stays as the default color until I hover over the other boxes with different colors that it color's change.

Comment: You should probably set all of the `isPressed` variables to false at the beginning of the `draw()` call.  Because by default, the mouse is not pressing any of the boxes, right?  You only set one variable to true if the mouse is pressed, and only for the box where it's pressed in the current draw call.  If you're still having problems, please edit the question with updated code and the entire `draw()` function.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help. I'll tinker with it some more and follow your advice